# C++ 4d array memory deallocation is slow

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-management

My code has a 4D matrix in it for some math problem solving

```
int**** Sads = new int***[inputImage->HeightLines];
for (size_t i = 0; i < inputImage->HeightLines; i++)
{
    Sads[i] = new int**[inputImage->WidthColumns];
    for (size_t j = 0; j < inputImage->WidthColumns; j++)
    {
        Sads[i][j] = new int*[W_SIZE];
        for (size_t k = 0; k < W_SIZE; k++)
         {
              Sads[i][j][k] = new int[W_SIZE];
         }
    }
 }

//do something with Sads...

for (int i = 0; i < inputImage->HeightLines; i++)
        {
            int*** tempI = Sads[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < inputImage->WidthColumns; j++)
            {
                int** tempJ = tempI[j];
                for (int k = 0; k < W_SIZE; k++)
                {
                    delete[] tempJ[k];
                }
                delete[] Sads[i][j];
            }
            delete[] Sads[i];
        }
        delete[] Sads;
```

The sizes are very large WidthColumns = 2018, HeightLines = 1332, W_SIZE =7, the memory allocation is very fast but the memory deallocation (delete) is very slow.
Is there a way to optimize it?
I tired openMP but it throws unrelated errors of missing DLL which are there... if I removed the #pragma omp parallel for everything works fine. but slow...

Comment: Are you running a release build? I have seen cases where a Debug build in Visual Studio took 100 times longer to execute than a Release build because of the extra checking that happens in a debug build like heap corruption testing. Also consider a 1D array.

Comment: For the love of all that's unholy in the Universe please use `std::vector` and an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I did it is not faster

Comment: @drescherjm I will change to release, I didn't know the factor of speed was so crazy in memory allocation, however I'm also trying to do TDD unit tests and run them in Debug mode, so I thought maybe someone has a better way. 1D array means of course indices games, but maybe it is the way to go. thanks

Comment: @Gilad Using `std::vector` and appropriate smart pointers isn't meant for speeding it up at all (in fact, will incur with overhead) but for readability. Your code is really ugly with the naked pointers (and pointers to pointers to pointers to pointers?!?!!), and arrays that can be replaced with `std::vector`.

Comment: That code has more stars than the Hollywood Walk of Fame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably be inclined to use a `std::vector`. Now memory allocation is taken care of for me (in one allocation/deallocation) and I get free copy/move semantics.

All I have to do is provide the offset calculations:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>

struct vector4
{
    vector4(std::size_t lines, std::size_t columns)
            : lines_(lines), columns_(columns)
    , storage_(totalSize())
    {}

    auto totalSize() const -> std::size_t
    {
        return lines_ * columns_ * w_size * w_size;
    }

    int* at(std::size_t a)
    {
        return storage_.data() + (a * columns_ * w_size * w_size);
    }

    int* at(std::size_t a, std::size_t b)
    {
        return at(a) + (b * w_size * w_size);
    }

    int* at(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c)
    {
        return at(a, b) + (c * w_size);
    }

    int& at(std::size_t a, std::size_t b, std::size_t c, std::size_t d)
    {
        return *(at(a, b, c) + d);
    }

private:

    std::size_t lines_, columns_;
    static constexpr std::size_t w_size = 32; // ?
    std::vector<int> storage_;

};

int main()
{
    auto v = vector4(20, 20);
    v.at(3, 2, 5, 1) = 6;
    // other things

    // now let it go out of scope
}
```

Comment: Why `auto totalSize() const -> std::size_t` and not `std::size_t totalSize() const`? Is there a subtlety I miss?

Comment: @YSC the two forms are equivalent as of c++11

Comment: I know, but why would you use the weird form `auto -> type` where you can use the form we are all used to for decades? Anyway I don't say that as a criticism, I was just curious.

Comment: @YSC I use the auto form out of habit, adding the trailing return type if I happen to need it (as I do in this case because i call the function prior to its definition)

Comment: @YSC although as you can see I'm not consistent :)

Comment: @RichardHodges I would just like to say that you can't init the storage vector in the initialization list since lines, and columns are not init yet, so I added storage.resize(totalSize()) to the ctor

Comment: @Gilad my constructor's list initialisation sequence default-initialises the vector's contents, which means the storage is allocated. see the documentation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector variant 2

Answer (score 6):

Using a pointer to a pointer to... is a bad idea because it will fragment your data a lot.

I would create a class ta manage the indices transform and use 1D array, it's a bit more complicated but it will be faster.

Anyway, a trick: nothing prevent you to build your int**** with pointers to a zone in memory that isn't sparse (1D array you preallocated) and then use it as a 4D array.

Comment: Richard  is right with his comment. I know it is bad I'm asking for better ways

Comment: @RichardHodges  That puts the question in the "too broad" category.

Answer (score -3):

The correct way to create, use, and delete a 4D array is this, using the closure of the statement group to delete the automatic variables.

```
{
    const int H = 10;
    const int I = 10;
    const int J = 10;
    const int K = 10;
    int h = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int fourDimArray [H][I][J][K];
    fourDimArray[h][i][j][k] = 0;
}
```

If you have a need to dynamically allocate, then use either STL's list or vector class or use something like this with perhaps inline methods to calculate the index of the 1D array from the 4D array indices if you need blazing speed.

```
int * fourDimArrayAsOneDim = new int[H*I*J*K];
fourDimArrayAsOneDim[indexFromIndices(h, i, j, k)] = 0;
delete [] fourDimArrayAsOneDim;
```

Comment: this is not legal c++

Comment: Corrected to compile correctly and provide some options. Apologies.