# How to change 4D dynamic allocated array into 1D vector?

Tags: c++, memory

this is a part of my original code, the code is too big to put it all in here, 
anyway my question is only related to Sads 4D matrix,
I don't want to use the int**** like it was suggested to me in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41173483/c-4d-array-memory-deallocation-is-slow)

```
int main()
{
   //4D matrix
    int**** Sads = new int***[inputImage->HeightLines];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < inputImage->HeightLines; i++)
    {
        Sads[i] = new int**[inputImage->WidthColumns];
        for (size_t j = 0; j < inputImage->WidthColumns; j++)
        {
            Sads[i][j] = new int*[W_SIZE];
            for (size_t k = 0; k < W_SIZE; k++)
            {
                Sads[i][j][k] = new int[W_SIZE];
            }
        }
    }
     ProcessRowsLoop(20, 1904, Sads);
}
void ProcessRowsLoop(int m_support, int m_height, int**** sads)
{
 for (int row_in = m_support - 1; row_in < m_Height_in; row_in += BNLM_OUT_SZ)
    {
       ProcessRow( &Sads[indexRow]);
    }
}

 void ProcessRow(int**** sads)
{
    int m_SAD_00[W_SIZE][W_SIZE];
    int m_SAD_01[W_SIZE][W_SIZE];
    int m_SAD_10[W_SIZE][W_SIZE];
    int m_SAD_11[W_SIZE][W_SIZE];

    RunAlgo(m_support, m_SAD_00, m_SAD_01, m_SAD_10, m_SAD_11, m_CP_00, m_CP_01, m_CP_10, m_CP_11, m_ColumnSADUp, m_ColumnSADDown);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < W_SIZE; i++)
        {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < W_SIZE; j++)
            {
                Sads[0][m_col_out][i][j] = (m_SAD_00[i][j] + color_penalty_weight * m_CP_00[i][j]) / (sqrt(m_sigma_patch[0][0] / pow(mnm, 2)));
                Sads[0][m_col_out + 1][i][j] = (m_SAD_01[i][j] + color_penalty_weight * m_CP_01[i][j]) / (sqrt(m_sigma_patch[0][1] / pow(mnm, 2)));
                Sads[1][m_col_out][i][j] = (m_SAD_10[i][j] + color_penalty_weight + m_CP_10[i][j]) / (sqrt(m_sigma_patch[1][0] / pow(mnm, 2)));
                Sads[1][m_col_out + 1][i][j] = (m_SAD_11[i][j] + color_penalty_weight + m_CP_11[i][j]) / (sqrt(m_sigma_patch[1][1] / pow(mnm, 2)));
            }
        }

}
```

In my new code I would like to replace the 4D matrix int**** Sads, with

```
struct VectorFourD
{
private:
    int _width, _height;
    int _w_size;
    std::vector<int> _vec;
public:
    VectorFourD(int width, int height, int size) : _width(width), _height(height), _w_size(size), _vec(totalSize())
    {

    }
    auto totalSize() const-> int
    {
        return _width * _height * _w_size * _w_size;
    }
    int* at(int a)
    {
        return _vec.data() + (a * _height * _w_size * _w_size);
    }
    int* at(int a, int b)
    {
        return at(a) + (b * _w_size * _w_size);
    }
    int *at(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return at(a, b) + (c* _w_size);
    }
    int& at(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    {
        return *(at(a, b, c) + d);
    }
};
```

you can see that i'm iterating two lines at the same time in the function processrow()

running over

```
Sads[0][m_col_out][i][j], Sads[0][m_col_out + 1][i][j], 
Sads[1][m_col_out][i][j], Sads[1][m_col_out + 1][i][j]
```

at the same time, my question is how do I change my code to work with the new `4dvector` for example

```
int main()
{
 VectorFourD SadsVec = VectorFourD(inputImage->HeightLines, inputImage->WidthColumns, W_SIZE);
     ProcessRowsLoop(20, 1904, SadsVec);
}
```

also change the function `void ProcessRowsLoop(int m_support, int m_height, VectorFourD* SadsVec)`
but i don't know how to continue from here, can you please help?

Comment: Why is `vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>` not an option?

Comment: @A.S.H why would I want to use that? i want to replace to a more efficient and easy to use memory collection, not stay with the same nested one. And also when freeing memory,  in debug mode vector<vector<vector<vector<int>>>> will take for ever, i'm running unit tests for very large images which are stores in this. so overall I want a 1D simple and fast memory collection.

Comment: By making it with a single linear layout, you are obliging the runtime to find a continuous free chunk, and moreover, indexing through it will not be more efficient as you will need to do 3 multiplications and 3 additions to find a single element. I am not sure that your choice leads to better efficiency. You should at least try this "standard choice" IMHO.

Comment: @A.S.H ohh thanks, I have tried it. thanks as I said, in debug it takes like 5 minutes to free the memory.

Comment: @Gilad, Can you post a small running code into github? There are many doubts that can be answered seeing that code. E.g. It would clean confusing things like your variable prefixes choice: Normally "m_" means "member [of class/struct]", but you're using it as parameter/local variable prefix. So is difficult to understand.